# What is the correct merge type for cloud-init sections in multipart MIME format?

Tags: terraform, mime, cloud-init

I am trying to merge multiple sections of cloud-init config together with Terraform's template_cloudinit_config feature for an AWS instance.

Imagine 4 templates (simplified here):

```
# template 1
hostname: ${hostname}

# template 2
users:
- name: "a"
- name: "b"
- name: "c"

# template 3
coreos:
  units:
  - name: ${service}.service

# template 4
coreos:
  units:
  - name: ${service2}.service
```

If I MIME encode these with cloud-config headers...

```
--MIMEBOUNDARY
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/cloud-config
Mime-Version: 1.0
```

What is the correct merge type to use?

Answer (score 0):

The template you listed is `cloud-config`, not `cloud-init`

Using data source `template_file`, I wrote it directly without test, could you verify if it works?

```
data "template_file" "user-data" {
  template = <<EOF
#cloud-config
# template 1
hostname: ${hostname}

# template 2
users:
- name: "a"
- name: "b"
- name: "c"

# template 3
coreos:
  units:
  - name: ${service}.service

# template 4
coreos:
  units:
  - name: ${service2}.service

EOF

  vars {
    hostname = "${var.hostname}"
    service  = "${var.service}"
    service2 = "${var.service2}"

  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ami = "${ var.ami-id }"
  ...

  user_data = "${ data.template_file.user-data.rendered }"

}
```